# Long-running Bluetooth Low Energy operations without blocking on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, thread-safety, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an architecture question to ask here regarding receiving large amounts of data over Bluetooth Low Energy, and simultaneously manipulating the received data. I'm building an Android application using Java. (With Android Studio)

To clarify a bit here, my application initiates a memory download with a BLE device and begins to receive information from the peripheral. I want the application to be able to store the BLE information as it is received and be able to do background (off-thread) analysis of the data while the download is in progress.

My question is how I should approach this. How can I receive the data over BLE and do background analysis without blocking the UI thread? Assuming I'm using a global list to store the data, how can I analyze the list in a thread-safe way?

Any pointers towards examples or suggested implementations would be beneficial.